# Mocking UIViewController from storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, uiviewcontroller, xcode-storyboard

I have a question about mocking a UIViewController in my Unit Tests that is from the storyboard. I have the view controller loaded from storyboard like this in the `setUp()` method which is fine:

```
var exampleVC: ExampleViewController!

override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()

    exampleVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("exampleVC") as! ExampleViewController
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController = exampleVC
    let _ = exampleVC.view
}
```

However, the issue is how can I then mock/override methods in `exampleVC`. I have tried to instead create a ExampleViewController subclass and create the mock class in the test method like this:

```
func testExampleMethod() {
    class ExampleViewControllerMock: ExampleViewController {
        var testMethodWasCalled: Bool = false

        override func testMethod() {
            testMethodWasCalled = true
        }
    }

    let exampleVCMock = ExampleViewControllerMock()
    exampleVCMock.testMethod()

    XCTAssertTrue(exampleVCMock.testMethodWasCalled)
}
```

This approach crashes on the test as the view and other IBOutlets are nil on `exampleVCMock` and don't get loaded when the view controller is instantiated this way (so the exampleVC needs to be instantiated from storyboard).

So the question is how I can instantiate the exampleVC from storyboard (so the outlets are connected correctly) but at the same time be able to override methods/create the mock correctly for my unit tests?

Any advice appreciated thanks.

Comment: If you are doing UI testing, why not using UITesting from Xcode ?

Comment: This is Unit Testing, not UI Testing? Are you saying I should be UI Testing this instead?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to test, but it seems to be related to screen rendering, so yes, you should probably migrate to UI Testing

Comment: Running into the exact same issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Joe Benton! When trying to test such scenarios, you can borrow all UI dependencies from the real ViewController you instantiated on setUp and apply them into your mocked ViewController.

For instance, if you have a UIButton and a UITableView:

```
// exampleVC is your real UIViewController loaded on setUp.

mockViewController.loginButton = exampleVC.loginButton
mockViewController.tableView = exampleVC.tableView
```

From now on you can even use these UI elements to validate something.